# Grouping SQL Server requests

Tags: sql-server, performance

This question is **not** about grouping in SQL.

Let's assume an application server sitting between UI of the application and a SQL Server. This server of course makes SQL requests to the SQL Server. For each such request there is some non-trivial overhead. I am curious whether there is a way to group several requests and send them together, reducing the communication overhead.

For example the server wants to make queries such as

```
Select * from teams...
```

and

```
Select * from users...
```

and instead of processing them separately it will send something like a  `List<sqlRequest>` and receive back a `List<sqlResponse>` (of course transparently to the programmer).

In my particular case I am using SQL Server. On a more general note, is there any SQL database server / SQL mapping framework capable of this? Is (would be) the performance gain caused by this worth the effort at all?

Comment: Well, at least in SQL Server, you can definitely send more than once SQL batch to the server for processing, and using a `SqlDataReader`, you can process multiple responses one after another....

Comment: The best way of "grouping" statements as the ones you show is to use a stored procedures encapsulating the business logic. What are you trying to attempt?

Comment: Well, the purpose of this is to reduce communication overhead by buffering the requests and responses, the requests may have no common context at all. Thus I don't think stored procedure is the right solution. Sending more requests and using the `SqlDataReader` is a way to do this, but I would think about something more transparent.

Comment: (btw thanks for fixing the formatting)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* achieve performance gains if

- The second result-set is based on the first
- The first result set is expensive to create

Consider the following

```
CREATE PROC GetTeamsAndUsersForACity(@CityId Int)
BEGIN       

   DECLARE @Teams as Table (TeamId int, TeamName varchar(10))

   INSERT into @Teams
   SELECT TeamId, TeamName
   FROM 
         Teams
   WHERE       
         CityId = @CityID


   SELECT TeamId, TeamName FROM @Teams

   SELECT
          UserId, UserName, TeamId
   FROM
          Users 
   WHERE
          TeamId in (Select TeamID FROM @Teams)
END
```

Notice how we're re-using the @teams to get the users and the associated teams without requerying the teams table.

You could achieve these result sets in other ways. For example you could retrieve the teamids from the first result and then pass that back SQL Server for the second set.

You could also  requerying team again e.g. `WHERE TeamId in (Select TeamID FROM Teams where CityID = @CityID)`.

You could also just get in one resultset `select * from teams inner join users....Where city id= @cityid` and then split them out on the client.

The relative performance of each solution will differ on the size of first set and the query time of generating the first resultset so you'll need to test to see which is right for your situation.

As for how to consume GetTeamsAndUsersForACity from the client. Assuming you're using .NET you can

- Use [`SqlDataReader.NextResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx)
- Use [LINQ to SQL via the IMultipleResults interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb399344%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- Use [DataSet.Load Method (IDataReader, LoadOption, String[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skef0k7a.aspx) or one of the DataAdapter.Fill()

If you're using an ORM you'll have to check for support of multiple results form a Stored procedure

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, even though this is helpful, I was more concerned about some (existing) layer transparent to programmer, which would buffer the requests and send them in bursts...(I must admit I am not good at making myself clear)

Comment: @user992990, maybe you mean something like asynchronous requests? The programmer needs to tell the application whether to wait for the response or whether to do it in the background - so it cannot be transparent, but async might help you.